# get selected data from 'select' and trigger an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
  <title>Pomodoro Clock</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
   <h1>Pomodoro clock</h1>
   <div class="grid">
   <div class="box food">Set the timer for
    <form method="get" id="settime"> 
     <select name="pasta"> 
     <option id="1">Pappardelle</option>    
     <option id="2">Penne</option>
     <option id="3">Farfalle</option>
     <option id="4">Bucatini</option>
     <option id="5">Angel Hair</option>
     <option id="6">Gnocchi</option>
     <option id="7">Orecchiette</option>
   </select>
  </form>
   </div>
   
   <div class="box clock"><span id="start">Start</span></div>
   
   <div class="box settimer">
            <div class="decrement icon"><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i></div>
            <div id="mins"><span id="defalut">Ready</span></div>
            <div class="increment icon"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></div>
   </div>
   <div class="box pause">Pause</div>
 </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the data from the *select* div when selected, store it and update the *mins* div accordingly, which now has a default text "Ready".

I want to make form trigger an event automatically without a submit button; understand I can use `<select onchange="this.form.submit()">`, but couldn't figure out how to do so using jquery.

Comment: Hello friend! Have you tried:
 $("select").on("change", function(){...});

Comment: @rossijonas hahha hai!! ok so i can just go to jquery and write the code directly i guess

Comment: @bom ✌️✌️... You have a more complete answer on this link from the other comment, that possible duplicate... the upvoted answer there, has a more complete solution than the tip I wrote. cheers!